# I am failing to correctly loop through an xml file with python, how can I loop through and return multiple different tags in the correct order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I have an XML file from which I need to return the text from various tags, CompanyName, FirstName, LastName, Content, Time etc.

So far I can return the text of every iterance of one of the tags using a for each loop, or I can return all of the required data but in consecutive blocks.

What I am struggling to find the answer to is, how to return the appropriate text from the specified tags in the correct chronological order as they appear in the XML document.

Below I will describe what I have already tried.

Firstly, here is the XML content I am parsing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<FileDump>
<Version>1.3</Version>
<Conversation>
<RoomID>1</RoomID>
<StartTime>09/09/2021 19:35:35</StartTime>
<StartTimeUTC>1631216135</StartTimeUTC>
<ParticipantEntered>
<User>
<LoginName>JJohnson</LoginName>
<FirstName>John</FirstName>
<LastName>Johnson</LastName>
<CompanyName>ABC LimitedCO</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>JJ@ABC.com</EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress>none</CorporateEmailAddress>
<Content> good Morning how are you today? </Content>
</User>
<DateTime>09/09/2021 19:35:35</DateTime>
<DateTimeUTC>1631216135</DateTimeUTC>
<ConversationID></ConversationID>
</ParticipantEntered>
<Message>
<User>
<LoginName>MMArks</LoginName>
<FirstName>Mark</FirstName>
<LastName>Marks</LastName>
<CompanyName>XYZ Corp</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>mm@xyz.com</EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress></CorporateEmailAddress>
<Content> what time is it? </Content>
</User>
</Message>
</Conversation>
</FileDump>
```

The following blocks of code are what I have tried so far;

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
mytree = ET.parse(r'sample.xml')
myroot = mytree.getroot()


for content in myroot.iter('Content'):
    for name in myroot.iter('CompanyName'):
        cname = name
    output = content
    print(name.text, output.text)
```

#This script will return:

XYZ Corp  good Morning how are you today?
XYZ Corp  what time is it?

first one should say ABC Limited

#I then tried this:

```
for content in myroot.findall('Conversation'):
     output = content.find('Content')
     FName = content.find('FirstName')
     LName = content.find('LastName')
     cont = content.find('CompanyName')
     print(cont, "\n", FName, LName, output)
```

#This returns

None
None None None

so it doesnt trigger an error, but when I ask to return the text within:

```
for content in myroot.findall('Conversation'):
     output = content.find('Content').text
     FName = content.find('FirstName').text
     LName = content.find('LastName').text
     cont = content.find('CompanyName').text
     print(cont, "\n", FName, LName, output)
```

#This returns an error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'" - even though there clearly is text I dont understand why its failing

#But weirdly the above block of code works exactly as I want it to when I use the following XML script that I got from the ElementTree documentation, which I have edited to add the tags I am looking for in the real script, the XML code that isnt working has been validated as correct XML so I have ruled out any errors there - I dont know enough about xml to spot the difference and understand why its not working:

(this works when combined with the last block of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <LastName>Johnson</LastName>
        <CompanyName>ABC LIMITED</CompanyName>
        <Content>
       Good Morning How are you?
        </Content>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
        <FirstName>Mark</FirstName>
        <LastName>Marks</LastName>
        <CompanyName>XYZ Corp</CompanyName>
        <Content>
        Good Morning
        </Content>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
        <FirstName>Keith</FirstName>
        <LastName>Keitherson</LastName>
        <CompanyName>WW Corp</CompanyName>
        <Content>
     Good Evening 
        </Content>
    </country>
</data>
```

and it returns the following result:

ABC LIMITED
John Johnson
Good Morning How are you?

XYZ Corp
Mark Marks
Good Morning

WW Corp
Keith Keitherson
Good Evening

other things I have tried are:

```
for content in myroot.itertext():
    print(content)
```

#This does return all of the available text in the document, but doesnt take an arguement to narrow down my search for the tags I need

As you can probably tell I am a coding noob and im trying to wing my way through this to solve a problem that has arisen.

I have no doubt that its a very simple and basic change that I need to make, but from my lack of knowledge combined with the vast amount of different ways that this can be done online I have confused myself and now find myself here.

I have tried to give as much info as possible, so anyone in the know should be able to point me in the right direction.

If there is anymore info needed please let me know

EDIT:

The desired output is as follows:

ABC LIMITED
John Johnson
good Morning how are you today?

XYZ Corp
Mark Marks
what time is it?

following the first suggestion the latest script I am using now is:

```
for content in myroot.findall('.//Conversation'):
     output = content.find('.//Content').text
     FName = content.find('.//FirstName').text
     LName = content.find('.//LastName').text
     cont = content.find('.//CompanyName').text
     print(cont, "\n", FName, LName, output)
```

This returns just one (the first) result from the specified tags as such:

ABC LimitedCO
John Johnson  good Morning how are you today?

EDIT:

I have had mixed success with answers I have received, the suggestion wont work perfectly on this block of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<FileDump>
<Version>1.3</Version>
<Conversation>
<RoomID>CHAT</RoomID>
<StartTime>09/09/2021 19:35:35</StartTime>
<StartTimeUTC>1631216135</StartTimeUTC>
<ParticipantEntered InteractionType="N" DeviceType="M">
<User>
<LoginName>JJohnson</LoginName>
<FirstName>JOHN</FirstName>
<LastName>Johnson</LastName>
<CompanyName>ABC Limited CO</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>JJ@abc.com</EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress></CorporateEmailAddress>
</User>
<DateTime>09/09/2021 19:35:35</DateTime>
<DateTimeUTC>1631216135</DateTimeUTC>
<Content>
Testing Content 1 
</Content>
<ConversationID>CHAT</ConversationID>
</ParticipantEntered>
<Message>
<User>
<LoginName>MMarks</LoginName>
<FirstName>Mark</FirstName>
<LastName>MArks</LastName>
<CompanyName>XYZ Corp</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress></EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress></CorporateEmailAddress>
</User>
<DateTime>09/09/2021 19:35:35</DateTime>
<DateTimeUTC>1631216135</DateTimeUTC>
<Content>
Testing content 2
</Content>
<ConversationID>CHAT</ConversationID>
</Message>
<ParticipantEntered>
<User>
<LoginName>SSamson</LoginName>
<FirstName>Sam</FirstName>
<LastName>Samson</LastName>
<CompanyName>123 CorpCO</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress></EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress></CorporateEmailAddress>
<Content>
Testing content 3
</Content>
</User>
</ParticipantEntered>
</Conversation>
</FileDump>
```

This returns:

ABC Limited CO Johnson JOHN not_found
XYZ Corp MArks Mark not_found
123 CorpCO Samson Sam
Testing content 3

Comment: `Content` and siblings are not direct children of `Conversation`, and that is why `content.find('Content')` etc. return None.

Comment: okay thank you for pointing that out, what would you suggest I change in order to execute properly?

Comment: You need `myroot.findall('.//Conversation')` and then `content.find('.//Content')` etc.

Comment: Given the XML `FileDump` (from the post) - what is the final data structure you need to have?

Comment: @mzjn thank you for your suggestion, when I run the .// on my script it will return no error but online returns the first expected response:

ABC LimitedCO 
 John Johnson  good Morning how are you today? 

any idea how I can get it to return all of the text in the specified tags please?

Comment: @balderman this is the expected return from the top set of XML:

ABC LIMITED John Johnson  good Morning how are you today?

XYZ Corp Mark Marks what time is it?

the actual XML file I need to run this on is 10's of thousands of lines long, so I have just shortened this right down for the purposes of this question

Comment: Please update the post and add the desired output. (based on the xml you have shared). Your addition should be a valid python data structure: list/dict/other

Comment: @balderman I have included the desired output in the original question but will update to make it clearer at the bottom, thank you for looking

Comment: do you mean: `ABC LIMITED John Johnson good Morning how are you today?

XYZ Corp Mark Marks what time is it?`

Comment: @balderman that is the expected output from the above XML, yes. 

I have taken the above as a snippet from a much larger file (thousands of lines) I have tried the .// suggestion above and weirdly it returns some of the results but then I receive this error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

The larger file is one I cannot share unfortunately.

Comment: @VBAKeith see my answer below. It works based on the XML you have provided. Isnt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like the below is what you are looking for

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FileDump>
   <Version>1.3</Version>
   <Conversation>
      <RoomID>CHAT</RoomID>
      <StartTime>09/09/2021 19:35:35</StartTime>
      <StartTimeUTC>1631216135</StartTimeUTC>
      <ParticipantEntered InteractionType="N" DeviceType="M">
         <User>
            <LoginName>JJohnson</LoginName>
            <FirstName>JOHN</FirstName>
            <LastName>Johnson</LastName>
            <CompanyName>ABC Limited CO</CompanyName>
            <EmailAddress>JJ@abc.com</EmailAddress>
            <CorporateEmailAddress />
         </User>
         <DateTime>09/09/2021 19:35:35</DateTime>
         <DateTimeUTC>1631216135</DateTimeUTC>
         <Content>Testing Content 1</Content>
         <ConversationID>CHAT</ConversationID>
      </ParticipantEntered>
      <Message>
         <User>
            <LoginName>MMarks</LoginName>
            <FirstName>Mark</FirstName>
            <LastName>MArks</LastName>
            <CompanyName>XYZ Corp</CompanyName>
            <EmailAddress />
            <CorporateEmailAddress />
         </User>
         <DateTime>09/09/2021 19:35:35</DateTime>
         <DateTimeUTC>1631216135</DateTimeUTC>
         <Content>Testing content 2</Content>
         <ConversationID>CHAT</ConversationID>
      </Message>
      <ParticipantEntered>
         <User>
            <LoginName>SSamson</LoginName>
            <FirstName>Sam</FirstName>
            <LastName>Samson</LastName>
            <CompanyName>123 CorpCO</CompanyName>
            <EmailAddress />
            <CorporateEmailAddress />
            <Content>Testing content 3</Content>
         </User>
      </ParticipantEntered>
   </Conversation>
</FileDump>
'''

NOT_FOUND = '__NOT_FOUND__'


def _get(ele, name):
    sub = ele.find(name)
    return sub.text if sub is not None else NOT_FOUND


root = ET.fromstring(xml)
elements = ['CompanyName', 'LoginName', 'FirstName', 'Content']


def loop(base_ele):
    for pe in root.findall(f'.//{base_ele}'):
        content = _get(pe, 'Content')
        u = pe.find('User')
        data = [_get(u, x) for x in elements] if content == NOT_FOUND else [_get(u, x) for x in elements[:-1]]
        if len(data) < 4:
            data.append(content)
        msg = ' '.join(data)
        print(f"{msg}")


loop('ParticipantEntered')
loop('Message')
```

output

```
ABC Limited CO JJohnson JOHN Testing Content 1
123 CorpCO SSamson Sam Testing content 3
XYZ Corp MMarks Mark Testing content 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write this, I did think about trying nested for each loops but couldnt get it to work either. the code you have posted works great on the XML that I posted above, but I have struggled to get it to work on the actual file I need it to - I will post an edit above with the XML I am referring to - the current result when using your code is:

ABC Limited CO Johnson JOHN not_found
XYZ Corp MArks Mark not_found
123 CorpCO Samson Sam
Testing content 3

so it misses the first two instances of 'Content' but picks up the last one

Comment: 2 of the `Content` elements in the doc belongs to `ParticipantEntered` and one to the `User`. This is why you get this result. So where do you want to take the `Content` from?

Comment: code was modified to support the xml structure.

Comment: thank you again for this it works perfectly now, I am trying to take this as a template and add in more tags to return, the main one im after in 'DateTime', when I add DateTime to the elements var, it only returns __NOT_FOUND__ - my lack of understanding here means im not sure why this is the case, if you could give any guidance on why that would be it would be much appreciated

Comment: I think it has something to do with the DateTime being 'above' the 'User' tag but im not sure what has to change, in the above sample XML it is StartTime